# Why does entropy increase in reactions that make more molecules?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

I used to understand this (more molecules ⇒ more degrees of freedom), but do no longer, because the total number of atoms is conserved, so translational d.o.f. should just be turned into internal d.o.f.
(at least considering only those reactions in which that is the case, no particle creation or annihilation).

Example:
Two separate H atoms have 3 translational d.o.f. each (x,y,z), for 6 d.o.f. total. I bring them together to form $\ce H_2$ and now have 3 net translational d.o.f. for the whole molecule, as well as 2 rotations, and a vibration.

In fact, the vibration has 2 d.o.f. for kinetic and potential energy giving heat capacity $\frac{7}{2}RT$ for a diatomic molecule.

So why does entropy decrease in the type of reaction with a form something like
$$\ce{ nA + mB -> A_nB_m }$$

Is it perhaps related to certain internal degrees of freedom only being “unlocked” at higher temperatures because of high minimum quanta of energy per d.o.f.?  If so, that would mean that at higher temperatures, entropy no longer increases for reactions that produce more molecules.

Comment: Your interpretation is correct. As a consequence, no molecules do exist at very high temperatures. They are all transformed into atoms.

Comment: And in the interim temperature region? Between unlocking vibrations and destroying the molecule, is the entropy change per increase in number of molecules, $\frac{dS}{dn}$, a function of temperature, inversely correlated with some power of $T$, where, because of the extra d.o.f. For vibrations, for some “hot” temperature, $\frac{dS}{dn}$ is actually < 0?

Comment: Be careful ! In the reaction $\ce{nA + mB -> A_nB_m}$ the entropy does not increase. It decreases

Comment: Right, thank you.  I’ll edit it to say decrease, but my point is still Why?  Because if this is true, then at, say 100°C, it shouldn’t. This seems too different from what we were taught.  I can understand relativity and QM as modifications that correspond in the classical limit, but “entropy increases with number of molecules” only at temperatures below which rotations and vibrations aren’t unlocked (~0°-100, maybe 150°C), and in fact begins to decrease as vibrations are unlocked... seems too different. It agrees over too small a regime and. It well enough.

Comment: An atom has 3 dof.  So two atoms have 6 dof.  A diatomic molecule has 3N = 6 dof if all dof's are accessible.  However, vibrational dof's are not typically accessible at room temperature, leaving the diatomic with only 5 dof's at that temp.

Comment: Right, so “$\frac{dS}{dn} > 0$ only near room temperature” sounds much too loose, and not a very good “rule of thumb”, at least not as applicable as I was led to believe.  I’ve often boiled things in a flask from 150°C - 200°C, and I know that many processes, in particular industrial ones happen above that. 

Also, do vibrations not have 2 degrees of freedom, for potential and kinetic energy, leading to heat capacity 7/2 RT? This means that not only does this “$\frac{dS}{dn} > 0$“ fail to be applicable, but in fact the opposite holds true above room temperature.

Comment: I think you are focused on the energy storage mechanism as the only way to generate entropy. But there are other ways to generate entropy. Entropy is added when molecules break apart due to the removal of constraints on the positions of atoms with respect to other atoms. That is an inherent entropy increase.